# Inactive status error received - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax request that is sent over to a file to grab information and return JSON.

Here is my request example:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "admin/actions/ifp_get_events.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data:
    {
        'elevation_name' : 'global',
        'function' : 'elevation_restrictions_events',
        'parent_id' : d.ifp_id
    },
    success: function(data){
            ......do stuff
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("error occured, please try again.");
    }
   });
```

Now I've been developing using Google Chrome and it works perfect but when I go to try this in Firefox or IE I am getting the following error:

The alert of coarse is being triggered and I have a response text of:

```
responseText:"
{
    "status":"error",
    "message":"You have been logged out due to inactivity." 
}
{"status":"found","code":1,"original_request":
{"elevation_name":"global","function":"elevation_restrictions_events","parent_id":"26"},"data_retrieved":[{"evt_for":"Game Room","evt_restriction":"","evt_select_ability":"hide","evt_active_ability":"disable"},{"evt_for":"Bedroom 5 w\/ Bath 5","evt_restriction":"Craftsman Entry, Kitchen","evt_select_ability":"show","evt_active_ability":"enable"}]}"
```

Note that once the error message was given the new status section is the correct response I needed.  I am just uncertain as to why this is happening in Firefox and IE?

Suggestions, thoughts?

If you need any more information please ask me.

Comment: So in other words, the code works fine in chrome but not in FF and IE?

Comment: @asprin yes, I am uncertain why I get that `you have been logged out...` message

Comment: We need to see the code in `ifp_get_events.php` to see why it's logging you out.

Comment: If there is login feature, login into the application on both browsers and then try again

Comment: Oh there is a login system, let me try that

Comment: @DavidBiga Cookies/sessions are not shared across browsers, so that would be the obvious problem.

Comment: You are asking why some unknown code produces a specific message? How do you think we would be able to do that?

Comment: Oh hahah I totally overlooked that one!

Comment: @asprin you are the correct.  If you post awnser I will give it to you!

Comment: Nice..posting in a bit

Comment: @felixkling I `console.log` the data returned.  I did not show it in the question.

Comment: looks like `session` problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser sessions aren't shared across browsers. In your case, you were logged in Chrome and hence the code was working as expected.

However, when trying out with FF and IE, you weren't logged in and hence the output was different.

Comment: It happens to the best of us..just one of those days

Answer (score 0):

add this line :

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
            },
```

after your data.

Since the valid csrf token is not going its logging you out of the site.

Comment: the OP hasnt shared that part of the code where he is sending this csrf token, I just assumed this can be an issue